# React Native useMemo in simple calculations

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-functional-component

So I have read that you should not use useMemo hook for simple (or not expensive) calculations. I have this following example were I check whether the application is Loading or Refreshing using useMemo hook. I use this constant in many places on my render to disable buttons until the current screen does not finish loading.

```
  const isLoadingOrRefreshing = useMemo(() => isLoading || isRefreshing, [
    isLoading,
    isRefreshing,
  ]);
```

What is the best approach here? For me, it does not feel right putting "isLoading || isRefreshing" multiple times in my render. I also though on using useEffect with those dependencies and then use setIsLoadingOrRefreshing inside it.

Comment: For simple calculations you can just use ```isLoadingOrRefreshing = isLoading || isRefreshing ```
This will be best is one liners

Comment: You are right because when you change the state (in this case isLoading or isRefreshing) in functional components the whole component will re render, and isLoadingOrRefreshing will calculate again.